# Data Select in Viz Chart Container

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using chart Container in SAPUI5 to show a column chart. How do I get the value of data points that are selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by attaching function to the VizFrame of column chart:

```
oVizFrame.attachSelectData(jQuery.proxy(this.getData,this));
```

And getting data:

```
getData: function(oEvent) {
   var aData = oEvent.getParameter("data");
}
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LsBxdynK5APAxdTHF8DO?p=preview), I did simple demo for you. It writes chosen data to the console log:

[image]